# How to get internal view width of WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Let's say you have DataGrid (standard) with width = 100 pixels, but you have such wide columns (and so many), that you have to scroll the DataGrid horizontally (entire DataGrid, not individual columns) to read the content.

```
+--------+ 
|very lon|
|<#=====>|
+--------+
```

I hope you get the picture. Ok, as I said, the DataGrid width is 100 pixels, but **how to get the width of view of DataGrid** -- obviously it is bigger than DataGrid?

#### Edit 1

I traversed visual tree of DataGrid to get ScrollViewer of it. Next I read ExtentWidth -- this value is however a bit too small. If I add RowHeaderActualWidth of DataGrid the sum is on the other hand too big. So, there has to be another factor (or completely better, more reliable, way to read internal width of the DataGrid view).

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if its too late to answer, but for general knowledge you can get it with

```
//in your class declaration
DataGrid gridInstance;

//in your method
Type type = typeof(DataGrid);
PropertyInfo pInfo = type.GetProperty("CellsPanelActualWidth", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
double actualWpfWidth = (double)pInfo.GetValue(gridInstance, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 4.0 available in front of me at the moment, but I would guess that you could do something like this:

```
private Double GetGridWidth(DataGrid grid)
{
    Double width = 0.0;
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in myDataGrid.Columns)
    {
        width += column.ActualWidth;
    }

    return width;
}
```

or, using LINQ:

```
private Double GetGridWidth(DataGrid grid)
{
    return grid.Columns.Sum(col => col.ActualWidth);
}
```

Comment: Almost -- I could do this, but there is small difference (because of grid lines, padding and God knows what else), and I need the exact number, the one WPF uses directly, not by "reverse-engineering". See my related question -- how to compute needed width for DataGrid:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577944/how-to-resize-wpf-datagrid-to-fit-its-content.

Comment: You are right - this would give you a close approximation.  I suppose you could get the template for the grid (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165848/where-can-i-find-the-xaml-templates-for-a-wpf-datagrid/4166007#4166007) to see if there are clues there.  Or, you could derive a class from the DataGrid and handle MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride (or one or more of other Layout functions) to see the magic therein.  I admit I don't know a lot about DataGrid specifically (hopefully someone will give you a better answer), but those are a couple of general approaches.

Comment: I have to focus on simpler ways, because this is supposed to be just a tool for resizing datagrid -- and it is already very scary, how complex it gets. Edit: I think I am bit closer to (imperfect) solution now with ScrollViewer, however some pieces are still missing.

Comment: It is indeed going to be complex - you will need to recompute any time anything changes (data, user resize, etc.).  You also need to account for things outside the DataGrid (for example, perhaps Styles that effect all TextBlocks), etc.  Does it need to be so exact? If so, you will need to (at least) look at the template.  The solution above may give you a "close enough" value that you could add a "fudge factor" for divider width (times columns.Count - 1) and padding, etc.  Depends on how exact you absolutely need to be.  If you allow user resize, the answer is probably "not very."

Comment: Well, I need to show optimal datagrid at start, not too big, not too small. It has to be exact -- it is matter of elegance, like picking perfect match of shoes (you won't except something "almost good"). I already introduced "ugly_factor" (to overcome the differences caused by paddings, margins, etc) and I am far from being proud of it :-(

Comment: @macias - I am sure that there is a way (waiting for a better answer here, which I will certainly upvote), but I am wondering if you are worrying a bit about a problem that, in reality, only you will see or really care about.  That's not meant to belittle the issue - it's just experience in messing with minutia myself that I've come to realize over the years that I should have been spending the time somewhere else.  If you think about it - if you open, say, Excel, do you really care about the size of the window and grid, or do you just resize it to your liking?

Comment: In other words, sometimes you have to just wear the black shoes with the gray tie, instead of spending your day(s) driving to all of the shoe stores in an ever-widening circle.  :)

Comment: Well, when I look at the iPhone app screenshot (most of them) I feel envy -- because everything there is so well matched together. It is very unfortunate that we are surrounded by half-baked products -- almost working, almost polished, almost reliable. And I am tired of this -- I think we miss a lot by current situation, and the trend of doing things just quicker, w/o paying attention to details -- I use Excel, but I don't admire it. I cannot fix it, but sure I can improve **MY** app. And this exactly what I am doing -- thus this question. And, it also feels great to do something with style ;)

Comment: Fair enough.  Just remember that your perfect size is temporary.  Again, I don't think it's a bad thing to make your app as good as possible - experience just tells me that sometimes you need to settle for good enough.  It's up to you to decide what "good enough" means.  I do hope that you get a better answer.

Comment: You are right, perfect UI takes a lot of time, but since I am a user of my app to, I am simply sick of having to manually resize the datagrid **every time** I run app. But I am aware, that I will end up with so-so solution -- in this case, datagrid too big, but big enough to avoid manual resizing the window.

Answer (score 1):

In Xaml you can just use, e.g.

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=DatagridName, Path=CellsPanelActualWidth}"
```