# how to get the default style and control template of WP7 control?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, msdn, control-template

they have the styles and templates for WPF and Silverlight controls published on MSDN.
but not for the WP7 controls.

So, how to get the default style and control template of WP7 control ?

Comment: Look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165848/where-can-i-find-the-xaml-templates-for-a-wpf-datagrid/4166007#4166007 and see if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your SDK folder

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Design`

or

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design`

You will find `System.Windows.xaml` and `ThemeResources.xaml` as well as folders for eah of the themes.

Comment: thanks, found it. by the way, why don't they have this in MSDN?