# How to set a background color of a listbox item on selection?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I have listbox in which i have an ItemTemplate and in ItemTemplate i have a DataTemplate in that i have a Canvas which acts as a button, so my requirement is when an item i.e. Canvas gets selected background should be changed, by default the selection should be the first item and when the selection is changed i need the selected canvas background color to be changed accordingly how can i achieve this looking for a genuine help thanks in advance.

I've Tried The below code :-

This is my XAML :-

```
<Canvas  x:Name="Canvas_Main" Margin="23,191,27,75" Tap="Canvas_Main_Tap">
        <ListBox x:Name="Listbox_Main" Height="534" Width="430" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="Listbox_Main_SelectionChanged" Tap="Listbox_Main_Tap" Canvas.Left="10"  >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas x:Name="cnv_Items" Height="100" Width="200">
                        <Border Height="100" Width="200" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FFD0D0D0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Tb_Value" Text="{Binding Value}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="26" Height="40" Width="195" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="2"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Tb_UnitName" Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="19" Height="40" Width="180" Canvas.Top="55" Canvas.Left="10"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Canvas>
```

And this is what i've tried in my Code Behind :-

```
private void Listbox_Main_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Canvas_KeyBoard.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                OutAnimation();
            if (Listbox_Main.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                myitem = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)Listbox_Main.SelectedItem;
                ListBoxItem myitem1 = Listbox_Main.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
                SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
                myitem1.Background = brush;
                Conversion_Logic();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19328365/2681948) will help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change background color of selected item in listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320208/change-background-color-of-selected-item-in-listbox)

Comment: No that doesn't resolved my issue..........